# Version control of sparse files

Tags: version-control

I need to put under version control sparse files.

I mean files like:

```
/etc/hosts
/opt/Sybase/config.ini
/usr/local/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

They are sparse in the sense that they are not in one single folder.

Git usually works in a single folder. Other version control tools do the same.

I need to put these files under version control because I need to track the entire configuration of a server.

Answer (score 0):

Fossil allow to add single file and do not track the whole dir of it

Somehow tricky, but

- Create new repo (or repos, if you have more than 1 LT in next step)
- Define common base dir(s) for your files - it will be place of "permanent" Local Tree (common dir is important, because Fossil doesn't allow add files to repooutside open tree)
- Open repo in this CommonBase
- Add files
- Commit
- After it you can open repo in any other location into "working" Local Tree, get all files in it, edit-commit, but don't forget "update" after commits your "permanent" Local Tree

HTH